# ejecutar archivo.php desde otro archivo.php con un boton

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

la pagina inicio.php  contiene un botón, necesito que ese botón ejecute otro archivo.php

¿Como puedo realizar esta acción?

Comment: Creo que deberías especificar más lo que necesitas ejemplo: tengo mi inicio.php y quiero que cuando le de al boton me envie a archivo.php, o quiero que cuando le de al boton por medio de ajax o cualquier otro tipo de comunicacion mediante post o get pueda ejecutar archivo.php. Investiga de ajax, get o post y te puedo ayudar a responder lo que necesitas.

Comment: Hola maghdiel,Es un sistema que un programador me dejo a medias y estoy tratando de terminarlo. Necesito enlazar ese sistema con la pagina de inicio, el sistema tiene libreria jquery y en su estructura tiene las carpetas js y php con sus respectivos archivos. intente modificar archivos creados , pero no he tenido buenos resultados. queria usar el evento onclick del boton , pero no me resulta.

Comment: Disculpa pero no entiendo la estructura o el problema exactamente, ejemplo has investigado por ajax, include ('archivo.php') para saber si es lo que necesitas o simplemente estas divagando por que realmente no se entiende tu pregunta necesitamos mas información para ayudarte.

Comment: acabo de revisar lo que indicaste , es similar a lo que existe actualmente en el sistema. pero centrate en mi pregunta. Necesito que el boton que esta en la pagina inicio.php ejecute otro archivo.php del servidor, en donde este abre el sistema

Comment: Para que se pueda entender mejor tu problema adjunta a tu pregunta fragmento del codigo que necesitas modificar, porque si lo que necesitas en lanzar a otra pagina con el boton lo puedes hacer agrupando el boton un <a href="archivo.php"> </a>

Answer (score -3):

Creo que ya hay una consulta similar a la tuya en StackOverflow, te dejo aquí el enlace para que le eches un vistazo.

[Execute php file from another php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841093/execute-php-file-from-another-php)

Comment: Esto se considera una respuesta de baja calidad :(

Comment: Ah ya vale, para la próxima..